# Rails undefined method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions, state-machine

Somehow this one is really perplexing me, everything is really there, but somehow it doesn't work:

neither one of the self.status_transition.update do not work

```
  require 'state_machine/core'
  class V1::Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend StateMachine::MacroMethods

  has_one :status_transition
  after_create :create_status

  def create_status
    self.create_status_transition if self.status_transition.nil?
  end
    state_machine initial: :draft do
    state :draft, value: 0
    state :placed, value: 1
    state :paid, value: 2
    state :canceled, value: 3

    after_transition any => any do |t|
      self.status_transition.update(event: t.event, 
       from: t.from, to: t.to)
      #self.status_transition.update(event: "dsa", from: "ds", to: "dsd")


    end

    event :place do 
      transition :draft => :placed
    end
```

**ERROR:**

```
2.1.1 :004 > o.place
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "v1_orders" SET "state" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "v1_orders"."id" = 19
  [["state", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-11-28 12:48:40.256820"]]
  (91.7ms)  rollback transaction
  NoMethodError: undefined method `status_transition' for #<StateMachine::Machine:0x00000107aa78e8>

o = V1::Order.create # => #<V1::Order id: 22, state: 1, user_id: nil, created_at: "2014-11-28 13:29:03", updated_at: "2014-11-28 13:29:03", vat: #<BigDecimal
:101c09fe8,'0.2E2',9(18)>> 

o.status_transitions # IS CREATED

o.status_transition # => #<V1::StatusTransition id: 23, event: nil, from: nil, to: nil, order_id: 28, created_at: "2014-11-28 13:25:55", updated_at: "2014-1
1-28 13:25:55">
```

`o.place` returns the above error .

Comment: it seems that `self` points to `StateMachine::Machine` and not to model itself. please check it

Comment: tried V1::Order.status_transition.update and got NoMethodError: undefined method `status_transition' for #<Class:0x0000010264a548>

Comment: class V1::Order < ActiveRecord::Base ?

Comment: what are other ways that I can refer to the class method in the model ?

Comment: you have specified `has_one :status_transition`? this field shall be in DB, have you migrated already?

Comment: yes i have, and something like: V1::Order.last.status_transition works

Comment: ok, so `self` in both cases shall point to **instance** of `V1::Order` class. please also aoid `#last` method, etc.

Comment: please show which value the `transition` var has. Also, you shall get instance of the `V1::Order` class from the `transition` variable, may be as of `object`, or `parent` methods etc

Comment: well now you see as much as i do

Comment: not quite: I meant about the `transition` variable that is passed into the block: `after_transition any => any do `

Comment: running out of ideas ;/

Comment: just debug it with `pry` gem

Comment: try this: `self.object.status_transition.update(event: t.event, 
       from: t.from, to: t.to)`

Comment: get undefined method `object' and pry doesn't really provide much more, well and I don't know how to use most of it.

Comment: here is the whole repo: https://github.com/undersky0/order-api maybe someone will want to see whats the matter with it.

Comment: ` undefined method `object'` if which class?

Comment: still for #<StateMachine::Machine:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65844/discussion-between---and-richardlonesteen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/state_machine/StateMachine/Machine#after_transition-instance_method) block shell be passed as value for `:do` key to `::after_transition` callback, so:

```
class V1::Order
 after_transition any => any do |order, transition|
   p order # disable this as needed
   order.status_transition.update(event: transition.event, from: transition.from, to: transition.to)
 end
end
```

Comment: If this still generate the error, provide output of `p order`, and remove `extend StateMachine::MacroMethods`

Comment: o = V1::Order.create
ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block  using 2.0.0 with rails 4.1.7

Comment: still get the same error: tried to create proc object without a block

Comment: @Richardlonesteen goto chat

Comment: Thank you Sir for all the help, really appreciate you spending so much time and effort with me. THANK YOU !!! :)

Comment: Yes, the solution in your post worked. looks pretty :) thank you again